# Create note in MB51 with GOS objects programmatically

Tags: abap, saprfc, bapi, function-module

Im working on creating a material document movement (MB51 report) and then creating a note to it. So far Im finished with creating the document and returning the document number.

And now I need to create a note to that document. I was not able to find out which BAPI/FM does this...

so can I kindly ask you, which BAPI/FM can let me create that note?
[image]

I want to do the same in code which I do by that way:

SERVICES FOR OBJECT > CREATE > CREATE NOTE